# Java Search array for number

Tags: java, arrays, search, boolean

I have a project where I need to search an array of 50 elements and not only print those elements, which is figured out, but I need to find a number, boolean check = false, say 10 and if I do print a message box that I found it!

```
import java.util.*;

public class IT145_Homework_5_4 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    double alpha[] = new double[50];
    boolean check = false;

    // Initialize the first 25 elements of the array (int i=0; i<25; i++)
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        alpha[i] = i * i;
        }

    // Initialize the last 25 elements of the array (i=25; i<50; i++)
    for (int i = 25; i < 50; i++) {
        alpha[i] = 3 * i;
        }



    // Print the element of the array
    System.out.println("The values are: ");

    print(alpha);

}

// Print method to display the element of the array
private static void print(double m_array[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= m_array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(m_array[i - 1] + " ");

        if (i % 10 == 0)
            System.out.print("\n");

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: just change the boolean check to true when you found the variable. And print out a messagebox inside that if loop.

Comment: I'm tired and not sure exactly where to put this search...I've looked on YouTube and found out how to search but it doesn't show it as this advanced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class IT145_Homework_5_4 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        double alpha[] = new double[50]; // all the values are whole numbers, why not make them of type int?

        // Initialize the first 25 elements of the array (int i=0; i<25; i++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            alpha[i] = i * i;

        // Initialize the last 25 elements of the array (i=25; i<50; i++)
        for (int i = 25; i < 50; i++)
            alpha[i] = 3 * i;

        // Print the element of the array
        System.out.println("The values are: ");
        print(alpha);

        // Searches for value in array 
        double valueToFind = 100;
        if(find(alpha, valueToFind))
            System.out.println(valueToFind + " is in the array");
        else
            System.out.println(valueToFind + " is not in the array");

    }

    // Print method to display the element of the array
    private static void print(double m_array[])
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= m_array.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(m_array[i - 1] + "\t\t");
            if (i % 10 == 0)
                System.out.print("\n");

        }
    }

    //Method to find element in array
    private static boolean find(double m_array[], double valueToFind)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < m_array.length; i++) //remember that arrays start with index 0
            if(m_array[i] == valueToFind)
                return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work...am I to put a value in valueToFind?  Also, I have to show a Message box....how does this statement do that for me?  Sorry new to java and want to learn...

Comment: where it says "double valueToFind = 100;" replace the 100 with the value you want to search for. To show a message box try "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The value is found/not found");
", with the message box do not forget to put "import javax.swing.JOptionPane;" at the top of the class. Also welcome to Java!

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void print(double m_array[]) {
    boolean check = false;
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= m_array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(m_array[i - 1] + " ");

        if (i % 10 == 0)
            System.out.print("\n");

        if(m_array[i-1] == 10){
            result = m_array[i - 1];
            check = true;
        }
    }

    if(check){
    //Print message box with value stored in "result" variable
    }
}
```

Comment: That works after it has printed 4 but not after it has printed all the numbers like I want it to....simple syntax....wow